# StateT and forM_

Tags: haskell, monads

How could I go about getting `put` to work on the StateT monad while inside forM_?

```
loop :: Integer -> StateT World IO ()
loop passes = do
    (scene, b1) <- get
    forM_ [1..passes] $ \pass -> do
        let b2 = foo b1 pass
        -- other stuff --
        put (scene, b2) -- this no longer puts into the StateT monad
```

Or is there a better approach all-together?

Comment: Why don't you think it works?

Comment: (Hint: your `get` is outside the loop, so only runs *once*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it works fine, for example:

```
--I don't know what World is so I can't use your example

loop :: StateT Integer IO ()
loop = do
    forM_ [1..10] put
    x <- get
    liftIO $ print x
```

running `evalStateT loop 0` prints `10` like I'd expect. `mapM_` under the hood does this:

1. Actually do the map, which for the above example returns a list `[StateT Integer IO ()]`
2. Do a right fold like: `foldr (>>) (return ()) listOfMappedValues`

It's not clear what exactly your expecting but this would let you put things into the State from a `mapM_`